# Cannot access webpages using python socket module. What is wrong?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm a beginner and currently learning networking in python and am using the socket module. Whenever I run the script, I get a "400 Bad Request" message. I'm not sure if anyone has faced the same problem, but I'm basically copying the same code as the one in the freecodecamp video and its not working. I'll put in my code below as well as the output. Thank you for your time and hope you can help.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(("data.pr4e.org", 80))
cmd = "GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n".encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 03 Jul 2021 08:02:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 308
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at do1.dr-chuck.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: `GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt` doesn't look valid to me, did you try `GET /romeo.txt  HTTP/1.0\r\n"`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use '\r\n' instead of '\n'.

According to the [HTTP Spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2),
"CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all protocol elements except the entity-body."